# On show action for fragment view

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock to load in fragments for my tab layout. Now i need to perform certain actions when a tab fragment is loaded.

I tried to use the `onAttach()` and `onResume()` but they are only called when the application is first loaded. Not everytime i open a tab.

Is there such function which is called everytime a fragment is shown?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [source code of the ActionBarSherlock](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock). I am pretty sure you will fast enough find something like a [`onTabSelected`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/fe0125aedd889f6f5d9bd8ca09e1e79d9ffc0c58/actionbarsherlock-samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/TabNavigation.java#L36) handler or [`getSelectedTab`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/fe0125aedd889f6f5d9bd8ca09e1e79d9ffc0c58/actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/app/ActionBarWrapper.java#L428) ...